# Is there any maven plugin allowing to generate a file listing implementations of an interface?

Tags: java, reflection, maven

I would like, before packaging phase, to obtain a list of classes implementing a given interface (for this file to be added in output jar). How can I do that ?

Comment: I highly doubt that there is some plugin you can use for this task. The easiest way is to use some scripting language to do this. Are you running Windows or Linux?

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov are you trying to expose me some solution relying upon regular expressions/grepping my way into the code ?

Comment: Yes, you could use shell script with exec plugin or Groovy one with gmaven plugin.

Comment: Can't you just generate the JavaDocs (which includes "All Known Implementing Classes") and copy the generated JavaDoc-file of your interface into your output JAR? Not exactly what you want and also quite dirty but maybe it's sufficient for your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since I've already implemented that a few times, I now have a ready to use method.

1. Add the [GMaven Plus plugin](https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus) to your build
2. Declare an execution using project classpath
3. in this execution, add the [reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) Java library
4. In your groovy script, find the interface ou want implementations of
5. Report classes implementing that interface the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc method would probably work.  Another option would be to write an ant script to do it.  You can use the maven any plugin to help accomplish this:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/